# facebook graph search for all events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does somebody know how to load all events with the Facebook graph api? I want to query all public events, but I have to specify a search string.

This is how to query on 'graph':

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=event&q=graph

But I can't seem to not use the 'q'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make sure you had the "user_events" permissions.

Then you can use open graph to get all the events a user is attending by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/events
```

You can find more details in the User API for OpenGraph here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this was not what I needed. I need to grap ALL events, and not the events of a user. Just all the public events.

Comment: To get all public events, non-specific to a user, you would need to know all the event ids, which i don't believe Facebook provides to you.

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843429/how-to-get-all-the-facebook-events